# Pyplot - How can I plot in needle/histogram style?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, histogram

I want to make a plot with a needle symbol, which is like in R:

```
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
plot(x,y,type ='h')
```

Does anyone know how to plot such figure in Python? Not a histogram, just x-y plot symbolized with needles..

```
>>> jan_avg
Jan+0    139.833333
Feb+0    158.318182
Mar+0    149.500000
Apr+0    106.750000
May+0    104.477273
Jun+0    105.159091
Jul+0     56.295455
Aug+0     56.295455
Sep+0     56.295455
Oct+0     53.659091
Nov+0     53.659091
Dec+0     53.659091
```

Here the first column is the index of the data frame jan_avg and will be my x-axis..

```
>>> jan_avg.plot() # What choices should I specify here?
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've got it:

```
jan_avg.plot(kind = 'bar')
```